# PHP shell_exec() output in html not the same format as Linux terminal output

Tags: php, html

When I run the code below I get the output on new lines however the spacing is wrong.

Example code:

```
  <?php
    $data = shell_exec("df -h");
    echo nl2br($data);
  ?>
```

Webpage output:

[image]

I used `nl2br()` to get the command on new lines which is close to what i want but how do i get the spacing to match the terminal spacing?

Terminal output:

[image]

Comment: Where is the output sent / viewed? Use `<pre>` tag for example.

Comment: I'm tired i cant believe I didn't try <pre> tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
<?php
  $data = shell_exec("df -h");
  echo "<pre>$data</pre>";
?>
```

Gives me this output in the web:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @ficuscr I got it at the same time you posted - cheers anyway